# html.haml vs haml in Rails view templates

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

What is the difference between using view templates in Rails as '.html.haml' and as simply '.haml'?
For example,
`show.html.haml`
vs
`show.haml`

Are there any particular advantages of using one over the other? Or is one of them a standard practice? The same question goes for other types of templates as well, like '.erb'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format matters when you're using Rails' automatic responders. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with.

So for example, with:

```
class CarsController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    respond_with Car.all
  end
end
```

The app will render `app/views/cars/index.html.erb` and `app/views/index.js.erb` when viewing `http://localhost:3000/cars` and `http://localhost:3000/cars.js`, respectively.

Additionally, this is an established convention in Rails-land, so it's just a good idea to do this anyway, even if you're not using the auto-responders.

Comment: Does it mean that it is preferred and standard to use '.html.haml' instead of using '.haml'?

Comment: I understand using explicit format might be necessary when using auto-responders other than for html format.

Comment: Yes, '.html.haml' would be the preferred standard.

Comment: @jtrim Thanks for clarifying this, but i think established convention & just a good idea is not an argument. I want to know exactly why i should follow the html.haml naming convention when i'm not using auto-responders. as far as i understand in rails 4 there is no responders anymore (respond_to, respond_with), its been extracted to external [responders gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders).